# How to traverse a matrix in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I'm new in python, please have a look on the code below

```
n = 5
m = 5
mat = [[0]*m]*n
print(mat)
i = 0
while(i < m):
    mat[0][i] = i
    i += 1
print(mat)
```

This code gives output like -

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

In normal C program, this should give final output as-

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

And I want this output, but i cant get this, in loop I'm just accessing **0th row by mat[0][i]** but python changes all the rows. How am I supposed to get this output? And even if there is something I'm doing wrong then how during traversal it prints correct matrix? Please explain me how accessing the matrix differs in python?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line

```
mat = [[0]*m]*n
```

You're just copying a reference to the same list. This will work as intended

```
mat = [[0] * m for i in range(n)]
```

The full code:

```
n = 5
m = 5
mat = [[0] * m for i in range(n)]
print(mat)
i = 0
while(i < m):
    mat[0][i] = i
    i += 1
print(mat)
```

Outputs:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The takeaway from this is that the shorthand `list * int` should be used for immutable datatypes (like `int`), as for mutable data types you will just be creating references to the same item.

### Numpy

You're thinking of your list of lists as a matrix, so you might want to just use [`numpy.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html), as numpy is designed to be much faster than nested lists:

```
import numpy as np
n = 5
m = 5
mat = np.zeros((n, m), dtype = int)
print(mat)
i = 0
while(i < m):
    mat[0][i] = i
    i += 1
print(mat)
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]

[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

### While Loop

Note that

```
i = 0
while(i < m):
    mat[0][i] = i
    i += 1
```

should be written as

```
for i in range(m):
    mat[0][i] = i
```

`while` loops have their uses, but in this case you're doing the equivalent of a for loop with less readability.

Comment: Thanks for alternate solutions, now i get this

Answer (score 1):

Using `*` to create lists in python isn't good idea. In that method, you link all lists and any change in any of them edit all lists.
The better way is using one line for loop to create lists.

```
mat = [[0] * m for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
[0] * 5
```

You'll creating a list repeating that `0` 5 times. Since `0` is immutable you get 5 different zeroes.

When you do:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] * 5
```

You'll doing the same thing, repeating the list contents 5 times. BUT, the list content in the second case is another list. And lists in python are passed by reference, which means you're repeating the pointer. Getting 5 pointers to the same list in memory.